# Remove "Save and edit plot in cloud"-button in plotly in offline mode

Tags: python, plotly

I already managed to remove the link "Export to plotly"-link at the bottom of the plot with the parameter setting `show_link=False`. In addition I want to remove the "Save and edit plot in cloud"-button.

I used the code from the docs and could not find any option the fixes my problem:

```
import plotly.offline as offline
from plotly.graph_objs import *

offline.init_notebook_mode()

data = Data([
    Scatter(
        x=[1, 2, 3],
        y=[1, 3, 1]
    )
])
offline.iplot(data, show_link=False)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ6me.png)

Answer (score 2):

To use in the Jupyter notebook you need to pass a dictionary to the config argument of `plot` or `iplot` as shown below.

```
import plotly.offline as offline
from plotly.graph_objs import *

offline.init_notebook_mode()


data = Data([
    Scatter(
        x=[1, 2, 3],
        y=[1, 3, 1]
    )
])
offline.iplot(data, show_link=False, config={'modeBarButtonsToRemove': ['sendDataToCloud']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, on plotly.js with

```
Plotly.newPlot(container, data, layout, {modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['sendDataToCloud', 'autoScale2d', 'resetScale2d'] ,displaylogo: false, showTips:false});
```

Here you will remove buttons sendDataToCloud, autoScale2d and resetScale2d. Along with that displaylogo and showTips is off.